# Ritual immersion for the cantor

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader, chasidut-hasidism, mikvah-ritual-bath

I pray with Chassidim. Before someone begins to lead the prayer, they ask if he underwent ritual immersion that morning.

Is there a (and if so, what is the) source for this requiring the cantor to have immersed?

Answer (score 4):

The Lubavitcher Rabbi Zatzal [Igros Kodesh 11:401](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15895&st=&pgnum=418&hilite=) explained the purpose of Tevila in the Mikva in the morning is based on the Rashba which is mentioned in the Magen Avraham 4 that when one prays he is like the Kohain who is doing the Avoda, and the Kohain always does a Tevila prior to doing the Avoda.

However since it is too difficult (אין כח בצבור לעמוד בה) therefore it is not enforced only in general.

Perhaps based on this there are some Shuls that require a Chazan to go to the Mikva prior to Tefila.

See also [Likutei Torah - Parshas Ki Savo - end of page 43](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16093&st=&pgnum=416) where it mentions that everyone agrees that Tefila is more accepted with a Tevila prior to it.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: Which one?.....

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35064/3073

Comment: Is the answer's 2nd paragraph also from the Lubavitcher Rebbe?

Comment: Is a woman's Tefila also more accepted with a Tevila prior to it?

Comment: What? You are contradicting yourself! You wrote "Zatzal". Your last statement only makes sense if you had written "Shlita" (an opinion you would be entitled to). :-D

Comment: @NBZ: Your question was already asked http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35064/why-do-women-and-girls-not-immerse-before-prayer

Comment: No, there I ask why they don't go. There may be a reason (and probable is) not to go EVEN IF their tefila would me more accepted. It is quite possible that if woman davens after coming home from mikve (before relations), her tefilla would be very favorable received.