# Why do women and girls not immerse before prayer?

Tags: tefilla, women, mikvah-ritual-bath

[According to Lubavitcher Rebbe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35062/3073), daily ritual immersion is a commendable practice, as a praying Jew is likened to the *kohen* who would always immerse before his *avoda*. Why do the women of those communities where men immerse daily not do so if they plan to pray?

Girls often have prayers at school on a scheduled daily basis (as opposed to married women). Does [wanting to prevent self-justified extra-marital relations](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28458/3073) really have priority over this commendable practice?

Comment: The following is not an attempt to answer, just pointing out: do we normally find that a person should take on a hanhaga tova that they know they will have to stop?  The Ramban says the chattas of a nazir is for stepping down from his loftier level.  You seem to accept that married women won't be able to maintain this practice as conveniently.  So it would be accepting a practice that is inherently temporary.

Comment: Yes, really. [15]

Comment: *a praying Jew is likened to the kohen who would always immerse before his avoda* - Were there any *priestesses* in Judaism while the Temple was still standing ?

Comment: @Lucian Jewish priestesses (which still exist) do not perform any temple service.

Comment: @Adám: I assume by *priestess* you mean a priest's wife, rather than a woman priest, right ?

Comment: @Lucian Jewish priesthood is patrilineal: A male Jew is a priest if he is the son of a male priest. A female Jew is a priestess if she is the daughter of a male priest.

Comment: @Adám: My point was whether your question's opening sentence is even applicable to women to begin with, inasmuch as (serving or functioning) priests were never women in the first place.

Comment: @Lucian Ah, that's an interesting thought. Maybe only a male Jew is likened to the priest, and so the transferral of merit in immersion stops by non-priest males, and doesn't continue onto praying females. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The source of immersing before prayer or studying Torah was an [enactment by Ezra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38485/what-is-ezras-immersion-%D7%98%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%90) for the purpose of limiting conjugal relations between a husband and wife by requiring immersion if they had a seminal emission during / after relations.  The original enactment also applied to women and to involuntary emissions.  It had nothing to do with ritual purity, but was solely for the above purpose, as the person may still be ritually impure after the immersion - for instance a woman who became niddah after relations and had a seminal emission is still niddah after immersing.

However the enactment was canceled in a later generation due to the peoples inability to keep it, and now immersion before prayer is simply a minhag that some men have taken upon themselves.

I would assume that women don't do it because there's no requirement for them to and why would they want to take on a minhag that's quite frankly so difficult, especially when it was originally canceled specifically because it was difficult?

Answer (score 2):

This is my own thought. I would be very happy if someone finds a source that says this.

Perhaps the reason ladies do not go to the Mikva daily prior to praying is a combination of.

1. There are times each month where she has Tumas Nidah and going to the Mikva then may lead to sin.
2. Although ladies have a Chiyuv Tefila, at times ladies do not Daven the entire Tefila due to  lack of time when raising children. They for sure do not have time to go to the Mikva on a daily basis.
3. Regarding girls as per the answer here [Do permanently unmarried women need to go to the mikvah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28446/do-permanently-unmarried-women-need-to-go-to-the-mikvah) this would lead to improper relations.

Yes going to the Mikva daily is commendable if it does not lead to sin. However it is not even a Halachic requirement. Therefore ladies do not go on a daily basis to the Mikva.

Comment: Maybe going to the mikve would enhance the remaining prayers so much that it would outweigh additional parts having to be skipped because time was used to go to mikve?

Answer (score -3):

Women are no less obligated for tvillas ezra than men. If anything more so. It was originally meant more for women. This has nothing to do whatsoever with niddos so I cant understand how it comes into the conversation.

Comment: Source?​​​​​​​​

Comment: mishna tosfos yom tov end of third perek berachos.

Comment: his wording. Because she will become tomai she wont be listening to her husband.

Comment: since I cant comment further will comment here. A niddah going to mikva is not useless. see the mishna I quoted.

Comment: One can never be fully sure one is not a baal keri since it can be mixed in the urine so going to mikva is always 'useful'. Why dont we give a kohen challah today.

Comment: mayim is not only a spring but also a well. Most women mikvas today are well water to save on getting rain water. But even so since they are 'pumped' up are not 'real' well water.

Comment: some say a zava also needs well water. It may not be the halacha, but today it would be very easy to make a mikva underground with a lift going to it for men and women.

Comment: @Arach I haven't seen that Tosfos YomTov but that sounds quite weird. Tevilas Ezra was instituted out of concern that Torah scholars would spend so much time with their wives that they wouldn't be able to study enough. (That's R' Aharon Lichtenstein's explanation, shlita; he's rejecting the asceticism approach.) That very much sounds like it's just for men.

Comment: Well the tosfos yom tov should be in your library. It is a very common sefer and I cant help it if it doesnt sound to your liking. The idea is that women should also help the men achieve their potential which is really their main purpose

Comment: @Shalom Ezra's immersion was obligatory to women as well - see the link to Rambam in my answer.